# PyvBox TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualbox

I have some python3 code interacting with a virtualbox machine via Pyvbox.

```
vm = vbox.find_machine(vm_name)
session = vm.create_session()
guest_session = session.console.guest.create_session(vm_username, vm_password)
guest_session.execute('C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe', [url])
```

With this code snippet which executes fine but always throws an error (from the gues_session.execute):

> TypeError: string argument without an encoding

I've tried encoding the URL with python3 libraries but with no luck.

Comment: put an r before the route guest_session.execute(r'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe', [url])

Comment: I still get the error